# React - Lifting state up from API fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Working with an API here and ran into an issue. I have lifted states up before but at this time I got stuck.

The issue I am having is that I need to lift the state up from the `.js` file I am fetching the API from, to the parent where it is being rendered. In the past I could have just used `onClick={() => props.hook(value)}` or `onChange`, but non of them is being used in this file.

The API fetch looks like this:

```
const ApiTest = (props) => {
  const [product, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [itemCount, setItemCount] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const options = {
      method: "GET",
      url: "https://asos2.p.rapidapi.com/products/v2/list",
      params: {
        store: "US",
        offset: props.offset,
        categoryId: "4209",
        limit: props.limit,
        country: "US",
        sort: "freshness",
        currency: "USD",
        sizeSchema: "US",
        lang: "en-US",
      },
      headers: {
        "x-rapidapi-key": "",
        "x-rapidapi-host": "",
      },
    };

    axios
      .request(options)
      .then(function (response) {
        setProducts(response.data.products);
        setItemCount(response.data.itemCount);
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className={classes.container}>
        {product.map((product) => (
          <ProductCard
            key={product.id}
            img={product.imageUrl}
            name={product.name}
            price={product.price.current.text}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

And that is being sent to `ProductCard` which is making the actual, well, product card. Looks like this:

```
const ProductCard = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className={classes.container}>
      <div className={classes.card}>
        <IconApp className={classes.icon_container}>
          <StyledApp>
            <Visibility className={classes.icon} />
          </StyledApp>
          <StyledApp>
            <Heart className={classes.icon} />
          </StyledApp>
          <StyledApp>
            <Cart className={classes.icon} />
          </StyledApp>
        </IconApp>
        <div className={classes.image_container}>
          <img
            src={"https://" + props.img}
            alt={props.name}
            className={classes.img}
          />
        </div>
        <div className={classes.information_container}>
          <div className={classes.name_container}>
            <h4 className={classes.product_name}>{props.name}</h4>
          </div>
          <h3 className={classes.price}>{props.price}</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

But all the product card is being rendered at my `Category` file, looks like this:

```
const Products = (props) => {
  const [limit, setLimit] = useState(48);
  const [offset, setOffset] = useState(0);
  const [itemCount, setItemCount] = useState();

  console.log(itemCount);

  const loadMoreHandler = () => {
    setLimit(limit + 48);
    setOffset(offset + 48);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.container}>
      <div className={classes.grid_container}>
        <ApiTest
          limit={limit}
          offset={offset}
          items={(itemCount) => setItemCount(itemCount)}
        />
      </div>
      <LoadMoreApp className={classes.load_more__container}>
        <p>You have viewed page x of x</p>
        <Linear current="500" total="1000" className={classes.progress} />
        <form>
          <button onClick={loadMoreHandler} type="submit">
            Previous Page
          </button>
          <button onClick={loadMoreHandler} type="submit">
            Next Page
          </button>
        </form>
      </LoadMoreApp>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I think that the part that is confusing me is that:
`ApiFetch` is parent for `ProductCard`, and `Category` is parent for `ApiFetch`.
So pretty much, where in the `ApiFetch` should I place my `() => props.items(itemCount)`? It cannot be on the `ProductCard`, and tried a `onChange` on the container, but did nothing.

Comment: Just do as you did with setItemCount, create a local state in the top component (Category), lets say `[items, setItems]`  and pass down to ApiTest both as props. Then in ApiTest use setItem to store the api response which should do the trick. Just take care that you don't create an re-render loop (your parent will be triggering ApiTest re-render, so you need to make sure it doesn't fetch the data again)

Comment: @Goran.it sorry for the late answer, but it worked! Thank you :)